# Why am I seeing 'reads' when incrementing a counter in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, erlang, database-performance

I am using Cassandra to hold counter fields for some analytics that we need to process.

I noticed that for a given write event (where a bunch of counters are incremented), there seems to be a 'read' operation.  This means that the reads are queuing while waiting for the 'write' operations to complete.

My understanding is that there should be no reads, and just counter incrementation writes for each transaction.

Some additional information:

- I am using Seestar (Erlang Cassandra driver)
- The increments are done by executing prepared statements.  The prepared statement is cached and not re-prepared every time.
- The statement is not called 'async'.
- We are using Cassandra v2.0.x

The output of Nodetool shows that there is about 1 read for every 3 writes.

Note that when I test locally in a single node cluster, there are zero reads - so this is just happening on our production environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There actually is a read involved in incrementing counters.  This article describes counters in pre 2.1 and 2.1 pretty well: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-1-a-better-implementation-of-counters

Comment: Thanks - This is ultimately the right answer, but I thought I would give additional context:  I ran the counter_add test in cassandra-stress, and there were no 'reads'.  However, the cassandra-stress script adds new partitions, rather than increments existing partitions.  Adding new partitions produces no reads, while incrementing existing partitions produces a read!  Thanks.